# Errors with initialization modules using npm

Tags: node.js, centos, npm

Cannot install gulp and others plugins because of the error, but express, socket.io has successfully been installed

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: archy@'^0.0.2'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.0","0.0.1","0.0.2","1.0.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:685:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:607:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-
client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab090.5
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the version of npm that you are using does not support semver's caret (`^`) operator in package versions. Upgrade to the latest stable version of node.js (v0.10.32 as of this writing) and the problem should be fixed.